# How to use custom tailwind css animations (react)

Tags: reactjs, animation, tailwind-css

I searched a lot but I really don't understand, please help me
This is the link with the animation
 https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/content-styles/animations/

Like we have to put it in the tailwind .css file

Comment: explain yourself do you have tw-elements installed? the docs seem pretty clear

Comment: I don't know which two elements do you mean? Can you explain to me?

Comment: just read the getting started https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/getting-started/quick-start/